# UITextField stroke attribute opaque in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am running into a strange issue while working on developing a Meme app. I am trying to create a UITextField that has a black outline with filled white text. I am able to create just a white text field and another that is outlined in black, however I cannot get both simultaneously. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the attributes I am assigning to the text field:

let attribs = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
            NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
            NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: 1.0
        ]

Here is what the app looks like:
[image: img 1]
[image: img 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has a page describing exactly the problem you were facing: [Drawing attributed strings that are both filled and stroked](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1531/_index.html). The trick is to change the stroke width to negative:

**Swift 4:**

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
    .font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
    .strokeColor: UIColor.black,
    .strokeWidth: -1 // Change here
]
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let attributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: -1 // Change here
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`.strokeWidth = 0` yields fill without stroke.

`.strokeWidth = positiveNumber` yields stroke without fill.

`.strokeWidth = negativeNumber` yields both stroke and fill.